# Rollup.js exclude some files from bundling

Tags: vue.js, config, vite, rollupjs

I am using Vue together with TypeScript and Vite. Inside the code I use a constant for the API-URL. My goal is to bundle the application but keep my `config.ts` (or .js) file "as-is" for it to be comfortably customizable after build. Is this possible?

I expect it to look something like this:

```
dist/
└── index.html
└── favicon.ico
└── config.js
└── assets/
    ├── index.at5r4h.js
    └── ...
```

When researching I stumbled upon rollup.exclude and rollup.external, but these do not seem to cover my use-case.